# Does VLC Media Player play videos with a resolution of 2.39:1?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm having trouble playing a movie on VLC Media Player on my laptop. Walk the Line has an aspect ratio of 2.39:1, and when I play it on the software it crops the screen. I've gone into settings and inserted said ratio into the option of force aspect ratio, and it still plays with a cropped screen.

Comment: You mean it crops the side of the image off-screen, or it 'letterboxes' [black-bars at top & bottom]? Most computer screens these days are 16:9 so a 'cinema' movie will almost always have a 'letterbox' look.

Comment: Right. That's the issue I've been trying to fix because some other movies like Interstellar or The Tree of Life play in full screen and look fine.

Comment: Right… ermm… which?

Answer (score 2):

VLC supports 2:39:1 aspect ratio. While playing your video, right-click on the screen, select Video -> Aspect Ratio -> 2:39:1.

[image: VLC - Video Context Menu]

Comment: IMO, Vlc uses the correct aspect ration if the video is "normal" - i.e. contains correctly defined metadata.